# How to change the size of tick labels present in the Chart

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js, mesh-network

We’re trying to change the tick labels of the chart. We’ve tried using a label input to increase or decrease the value and tried to extract the value with the help of ***getElementById***. Then we define the label size inside the ***Plotly.restyle*** tag.

The code:

```
    <head>
    <!-- Load plotly.js into the DOM -->
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.24.1.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="number" id="LabelSizeInput" placeholder="Enter label size" />
    <div id='myDiv'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
</body>
```

The JavaScript Code :

```
function gaussianRand() {
  var rand = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i += 1) {
    rand += Math.random();
  }
  return (rand / 6) - 0.5;
}

var X = [],
  Y = [],
  n = 100000,
  i;

for (i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
  X.push(gaussianRand());
  Y.push(gaussianRand());
}

var data = [{
  type: "scattergl",
  mode: "markers",
  marker: {
    line: {
      width: 1,
      color: '#404040'
    }
  },
  x: X,
  y: Y
}];

var layout = {
  xaxis: {
    tickfont: {
      size: 12 // Set the desired size for x-axis tick values
    }
  },
  yaxis: {
    tickfont: {
      size: 12 // Set the desired size for y-axis tick values
    }
  }
};


Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);

var inputElement = document.getElementById('LabelSizeInput');
inputElement.addEventListener('input', function() {
  var label_size = parseInt(inputElement.value);
  if (!isNaN(label_size)) {
    Plotly.restyle('myDiv', {
      'xaxis.tickfont.size': label_size,
      'yaxis.tickfont.size': label_size,
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Plotly.restyle`](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyrestyle) is able to change only attributes in the data array, while the axes properties are not related to data, they are *layout properties*.

This, the function you should use is [`Plotly.relayout`](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyrelayout), with the same argument.

```js
Plotly.relayout('myDiv', {
  'xaxis.tickfont.size': label_size,
  'yaxis.tickfont.size': label_size,
});
```

[Code pen](https://codepen.io/kikondo/pen/zYMzOKK?editors=0010) with full code.

One may also consider using [`Plotly.update`](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyupdate), that is able to do both data and layout updates.